# P2O5 concentration % based on a 75% Phosphoric Acid Solution

Tags: elemental-analysis

I have a very poor chemical background, so please be indulgent in the case my question seems silly.
I need this clarification for a practical application:

If I want to obtain a P2O5 concentration of 4,7 % in my final solution, what % of Phoshoric Acid Solution  at 75% I need to put in?

My guess is about 8,7 % of 75% Phoshoric Acid Solution, is it that correct?

Comment: Why guess and not simple calculation? 1% P2O5 is equivalent 1.3807% H2PO4. The needed mass of H3PO4 solution is inversely proportional to its percentage. Needed volume of H3PO4 solution is equal to its mass and density ratio.

Answer (score 1):

Congratulations ! Your calculation is correct. Here is the proof.
$1$ mole $\ce{P2O5}$ weighs $142$ g, and produces $2$ moles $\ce{H3PO4}$, which weighs $2·98 $ g = $196$ g $\ce{H3PO4}$. So pure phosphoric acid can be made with $142/196 = 72.4 $% $\ce{P2O5}$.

As a consequence, a solution containing $75$% phosphoric acid can be made with $0.75·0.72.4$ % = $54.3$ % $\ce{P2O5}$.

If now you want to dilute it to get a solution containing $4.7$% $\ce{P2O5}$, you have to take $4.7/54.3 = 8.65$% of your initial solution.

All these values are supposed to be made in mass, and not in volume. Let's transform these results into volumes.

In tables, $75$% $\ce{H3PO4}$ has a density of $1.579$. $\ce{H3PO4}$ coming from $4.7$ % $\ce{P2O5}$ contains $6.5$ % $\ce{H3PO4}$ and has a density of $1.034$. As a consequence, if you want to make $1$ liter containing $6.5$% $\ce{H3PO4}$, this liter weighs $1034$ g. And it should be done with $0.0865·1034 = 89.3$ g $\ce{H3PO4}$. And this mass of $\ce{H3PO4}$ is contained in a mass $m$ and a volume $V$ of phosphoric acid (density $1.579$). $m = 89.3$ g/$0.75 = 119$ g solution; and $V = 119 $g$/1.576$ g/mL = $75.5$ mL

Conclusion. To make exactly $1.000$ liter of the final solution, you have to measure $75.5$ mL of the initial $75$% solution, put it in a $1$ liter flask, then dilute with enough water so as to obtain exactly $1$ liter at the end.

Comment: OP beware of using a scale

Comment: @Alchimista. A scale ? What do you mean ?

Comment: I mean something to measure mass. This might be the case in which a perfectly correct answer can be wrong in practice. Unless OP use a scale, in fact.

Comment: Your calculations are for mass context. For volumes, you have to include density.